# Import Configurator Error for Python Pyramid

Tags: python, pyramid

i'm trying to learn python pyramid  for linux and following the pylonsproject documentation in doing so.I'm also new to linux.

I've installed everything correctly(I'm pretty sure), but when i invoke my helloworld.py, i got this following error

> ImportError: No module named pyramid.config

the documentation says this should be the path to the file

> $ /path/to/your/virtualenv/bin/python helloworld.py

but i'm confused as the python after the bin is a executable not a directory? my env is located in the Downloads folder

Thanks!

Comment: I had the same problem as you and just solved it, do you still need help?

Answer (score 3):

These symptoms are almost always a misuse of the virtualenv in one way or another.

1) Make sure you are running the virtualenv

```
$ env/bin/python helloworld.py
```

2) Make sure you installed pyramid into the virtualenv

```
$ env/bin/python
>>> import pyramid.config
# ImportError or not?
```